# porque mi funcion anonima dentro de reduce no funciona dentro de otra funcion

Tags: javascript

mi duda es la siguiente tengo esta funcion y cuando uso reduce para obtener el numero mayor y menor cuando uso arrow function como en mayor me da el resultado pero cuando una funcion regular me da undefined... pero si let menor lo llevo fuera del la funcion sumaMayorMenor2 funciona bien... a que se debe esto?? muchas gracias por sus respuestas de antemano

```
function sumaMayorMenor2(arr){  
 console.log(arr)
    let menor = arr.reduce(function(num3,num4) {if(num3>num4){
        return num3=num4
    }})
    let mayor = arr.reduce((num1,num2)=> num1<num2 ? num1=num2 : num1)
    console.log(mayor,menor)
return(console.log(menor+mayor))

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no está en como la defines (funciona con ambos metodos), el problema esta en que la funcion de menor no hace lo que debería, pues en caso de que el numero num3 sea menor, no estas retornando nada.
Puedes corregirla asi:

```js
function sumaMayorMenor2(arr){  
 console.log(arr)
    let menor = arr.reduce(function(num3,num4) {
      if(num3>num4){
        return num4
      } else {
        return num3;
      }
    })
    let mayor = arr.reduce((num1,num2)=> num1<num2 ? num1=num2 : num1)
    console.log(mayor,menor)
return(console.log(menor+mayor))

 }
 
 sumaMayorMenor2([2,8,7,3,9,6])
```

O mejor, si las quiere compactas, así:

```js
function sumaMayorMenor2(arr){  
 console.log(arr)
    let menor = arr.reduce((num3,num4) => num3>num4 ? num4: num3)
    let mayor = arr.reduce((num1,num2)=> num1<num2 ? num2 : num1)
    console.log(mayor,menor)
    return(console.log(menor+mayor)) //No tiene mucho sentido retornar un console.log

 }
 
 sumaMayorMenor2([2,8,7,3,9,6])
```

Comment: Si es por compactar... `Math.min(...arr) + Math.max(...arr)`

Comment: si ya lo corregí el problema estaba entonces en que si no se cumplía la condición no retornaba nada cierto? faltaba el else que en este caso para reduce es obligatorio... gracias